# Wifi Problem in HP bs542tu after booting with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, intel-wireless

There's problem with my wifi. I do almost everything that I can. 
When I `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` then it show output like this.
I can surf browser through connecting with data cable but wifi is not showing and in setting it said that Wireless adapter is not found.

```
 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
Kernel modules: wl
```

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Help me ASAP.

Comment: Edit it @pomsky now help me.

Comment: What can I do now?

Comment: But @pomsky they said that it won't work in ubuntu 18.04